# How to change the orientation for an overlapbox and a gizmo?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

after a good amount of searching I haven't been able to find out how to change the rotation of my overlap boxes  set up and the gizmo used to visualize them.

```
//draw a hitbox in front of the character to see which objects it collides with
Vector3 boxPosition = transform.position + (Vector3.up * lastAttack.collHeight) 
        + Vector3.right * lastAttack.collDistance;
Vector3 boxSize = new Vector3 (lastAttack.CollSize/2, lastAttack.CollSize/2, hitZRange/2);
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(boxPosition, boxSize, Quaternion.identity, 
        HitLayerMask);
```

I'm using it for damage calculation. I want the OverlapBox to take the same rotation of the player and always be in front of the player.

```
void OnDrawGizmos(){
    if (lastAttack != null && (Time.time - lastAttackTime) < lastAttack.duration) {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Vector3 boxPosition = transform.position + (Vector3.up * lastAttack.collHeight) 
                + Vector3.right * ((int)lastAttackDirection * lastAttack.collDistance);
        Vector3 boxSize = new Vector3 (lastAttack.CollSize, lastAttack.CollSize, hitZRange);
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube (boxPosition, boxSize);
    }
}
```

Draw the Box Overlap as a gizmo to show where it currently is testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the overlap box inherit the transform's rotation, you can use `transform.rotation` instead of `Quaternion.identity` for the overlap box's rotation.

For the gizmo, it's a little more complex. One way to fix this is to change the Gizmo `matrix` to be the local transform matrix with `Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix`, which will make the gizmo inherit the player's rotation. But, it will also make the gizmo's position be relative to the player's local position. So, you'll need to convert the world position `boxPosition` to local position before you draw the gizmo. You can use `transform.InverseTransformPoint` to do this.

You may want to restore the gizmo settings to what they were previously or it could result in unexpected behaviour in other places where `Gizmos` is used.

Altogether:

```
//draw a hitbox in front of the character to see which objects it collides with
Vector3 boxPosition = transform.position + (Vector3.up * lastAttack.collHeight) 
        + Vector3.right * lastAttack.collDistance;
Vector3 boxSize = new Vector3 (lastAttack.CollSize/2, lastAttack.CollSize/2, hitZRange/2);
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(boxPosition, boxSize,
        transform.rotation, HitLayerMask);

...

void OnDrawGizmos(){
    if (lastAttack != null && (Time.time - lastAttackTime) < lastAttack.duration) {

        // cache previous Gizmos settings
        Color prevColor = Gizmos.color;
        Matrix4x4 prevMatrix = Gismos.matrix;

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix; 

        Vector3 boxPosition = transform.position + (Vector3.up * lastAttack.collHeight) 
                + Vector3.right * ((int)lastAttackDirection * lastAttack.collDistance);

        // convert from world position to local position 
        boxPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(boxPosition); 

        Vector3 boxSize = new Vector3 (lastAttack.CollSize, lastAttack.CollSize, hitZRange); 
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube (boxPosition, boxSize);

        // restore previous Gizmos settings
        Gizmos.color = prevColor;
        Gizmos.matrix = prevMatrix;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you I have tried many ways and also searching I haven't been able to find out how to change the rotation, your answer really helped me to understand this.

Comment: @NoahLc Don't forget to cache the gizmos state prior to making the color and matrix changes, and then set back after you are done with the draw calls. Otherwise all your gizmos will be changed.